# How can I add a Boolean field to MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, boolean

It seems I should use tinyint(); but I don't know how to implement it?

The question is what is your recommendation if I need to have a boolean field in MySQL DB and modify it´s value with PHP

Comment: A boolean field can also be interpreted as 1's and 0's so having a tinyint field will result in a faster database. And if you index it even faster. All of these answers below are off value to you! @Felix @Matthew @Haim good job

Comment: @etbal Yes indeed, all VERY helpful!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yep, `TINYINT(1)` is the way to go... you can also use [`BOOL` or `BOOLEAN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html) which are synonyms (so it does not make a difference).

`0` evaluates to `false` in PHP and `1` to `true` (actually, any other number than `0` evaluates to `true`, but `1` is normally used).

Comment: @Felix Kling not any other number than 0 evaluates to true http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html

Comment: @Viswanathan: Actually I was talking about PHP in this case, not MySQL.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer none of bool, BIT, TINYINT(1). because none of them are actually boolean. You can check the following link for 'why':

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html

I would better use : ENUM ('false', 'true') not null - as datatype. You can pass 'true' or 'false' (as strings) from PHP. And it will take only 1 byte to store it!

Comment: Why not  ENUM ('0', '1')  instead

Comment: Actually the string `'false'` is, ironically, truey in PHP.

Comment: @tormuto yes, you can. that would help auto-type casting in PHP when reading. But with ENUM it's not a safe practice to do it as you may forget to pass strings from PHP. What would happen if someone mistakenly declares ENUM('1', '0')? I saw many codes like ('yes', 'no').

Answer (score 2):

You're correct that the general solution is `tinyint(1)`.  You can use BOOL for short:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
         flag BOOL
       );
```

Answer (score 2):

you have option of tinyint(1)  or bit

insert 0 or 1 to this field

see this post of the difference  :

[Tinyint vs Bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488811/tinyint-vs-bit)

Answer (score 0):

I think since you actually want to enforce a boolean (0,1) constraint on a mysql table field, the best shot is uning enum

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(
    boolean_field_name ENUM('0', '1')
);
```