# MySQL - restrict tinyint column

Tags: mysql, constraints, restriction

In MySQL db, I have a table with users' addresses:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_address` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `street` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `number` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `city` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `zip` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `is_main` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)
```

The number of addresses per user is not limited, but I want the `is_main` to be `1` only once per user, to indicate the main user's address. All other user's addresses will have `is_main = 0`.

Can this be restricted anyhow on the MySQL level?

(`ALTER TABLE user_address
    ADD UNIQUE INDEX is_main (is_main, user_id);` didn't help as there are several records with `is_main=0`...)

Comment: I don't think it's possible, like you said yourself you can create an unique index on `is_main, user_id`, but you can only have 2 addresses then (one with is_main = 1 and one with is_main = 0). You need to restrict it another way then, in your code for example. Before you insert it, do a check if there are any rows with is_main = 1.

Answer (score 1):

i came across this looking for something similar... i think you (and likely me in my search) are mistaking `TINYINT(1)` for `BIT(1)`.

See here: [MySQL Boolean "tinyint(1)" holds values up to 127?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401673/mysql-boolean-tinyint1-holds-values-up-to-127)

and here: [Difference between "int" and "int(3)" data types in my sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562322/difference-between-int-and-int3-data-types-in-my-sql)

`TINYINT` is a byte-storage type (as are the other ints), where defining the length (`TINYINT(1)`) only affects the **displayed** value, not the actual **stored** value. The *stored* size is defined by the type itself ([MySql Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/integer-types.html))

`BIT` is more like string types in that the length (`BIT(1)`) defines how many will be **stored** (like `CHAR(5)` will store exactly 5 characters). So `BIT(1)` is more akin to a real boolean.

For your purposes, a simple unsigned `TINYINT` in the unique key may be sufficient, unless you anticipate users having more than 255 addresses. However, it will be up to your application to identify the 0-valued row as the main address (which kinda warps the semantics of the name `is_main`, so perhaps "`address_index`"?). i think it'll be a challenge even then if the main address is allowed to change (which is logical). You may need to set some controls with triggers so that when an address record is set to "main" (0), all others for that user are updated to distinct non-0 values. Bleh. :(