# What Data Type to Store 0, 1, -1 values only?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms, sqldatatypes

I tried creating a field as a `TINYINT(1)`, `NOT NULL` and a `DEFAULT` value of **-1** to indicate 'unknown', but I got this error from my client:

> Error altering *MyTable*: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

I also tried making the length 2 and got the same message

Guessing `TINYINT` isn't the right data type for this kind of designation, but what is?

EDIT: I got it working after reading Ed Cottrell's comment. I think there was an extra character somewhere, here was the statement that my client (using Querious for Mac) generated:

```
ALTER TABLE `DBName`.`MyTable`
CHANGE COLUMN `MyColumn` `MyColumn` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT -1  COMMENT ''
AFTER `MyOtherColumn`;
```

Noticed that `COMMENT` there and made sure everything was clean.

Other comments and answers were appreciated; I have decided to let `NULL` mean unknown in this case

Comment: I believe this answer will work for you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401673/mysql-boolean-tinyint1-holds-values-up-to-127

Comment: Maybe you should use nullable field, and set `null` as *unknown*?

Comment: Why not let `NULL` represent unknown?

Comment: This sounds like an actual typo; can you post the full `ALTER` statement?

Comment: @EdCottrell I added the statement to the question, thanks :)

Comment: Hi Ed, you were right somehow some kind of "comment" made it's way in there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should store this as a bit (if you care about storage size), and let `NULL` mean "unknown".

```
field bit(1) default NULL,
```

It seems strange to declare a field to be `not null` and then to have a special value that, essentially, means `NULL`.

EDIT:

The following syntax "works" on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09647/1):

```
create table t (
  val int,
  flag tinyint(1) default -1
 );
```

"works" is in quotes because the default value prints as "1" rather than "-1" -- after all, the `(1)` is saying just print one digit.

Perhaps in some earlier versions of MySQL it generates an error when it sees that `-1` won't display correctly.  (To be honest, that would surprise me.)

Comment: As an aside, I notice you haven't put a field length in the BIT field in your statement, is this not necessary? Also, I don't think I'll get any storage savings if it's my only BIT column (which it happens to be in this table); I believe BIT takes up 1 byte for up to 8 columns, and TINYINT also takes up one byte does it now? Thanks :)

Comment: @Drewdavid . . . I added the length in.  Although MySQL accepts `bit` without the length, the documentation suggests that the length is required.

Comment: `tinyint(1)` does **not** limit the values of that column to one digit.