# Doctrine returns always the same record & schema:update fails

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to use an existing database with Symfony/Doctrine and nothing seems to work.

The import (database to mapping) was successful and the generated files in src/xxx/Entity look good.

However, there are two problems:

**The problem**:

Doctrine wants to run 13 queries on my ridiculously small database. I thought that after the import, Doctrine would sync with the online database. Yet, this wasn't the case at all.

It would be better if I didn't modify the database (because of reasons) and in any case the `doctrine:schema:update` fails completely:

```
### doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
ALTER TABLE categorie CHANGE id id TINYINT(1) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE produit CHANGE id id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, CHANGE categorie_id categorie_id TINYINT(1) DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE derniere_maj derniere_maj DATETIME NOT NULL;
DROP INDEX fk_produit_categorie1_idx ON produit;
CREATE INDEX IDX_29A5EC27BCF5E72D ON produit (categorie_id);
ALTER TABLE commande_client CHANGE id id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, CHANGE client_id client_id INT DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE date_creation date_creation DATETIME NOT NULL, CHANGE no_confirmation no_confirmation INT NOT NULL;
DROP INDEX fk_commande_client_client1_idx ON commande_client;
CREATE INDEX IDX_C510FF8019EB6921 ON commande_client (client_id);
ALTER TABLE commande_client_vers_produit DROP quantite, CHANGE commande_client_id commande_client_id INT NOT NULL, CHANGE produit_id produit_id INT NOT NULL;
DROP INDEX fk_commande_client_has_produit_commande_client1_idx ON commande_client_vers_produit;
CREATE INDEX IDX_6E3497729E73363 ON commande_client_vers_produit (commande_client_id);
DROP INDEX fk_commande_client_has_produit_produit1_idx ON commande_client_vers_produit;
CREATE INDEX IDX_6E349772F347EFB ON commande_client_vers_produit (produit_id);
ALTER TABLE client CHANGE id id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL;

### doctrine:schema:update --force

  [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]                                                                               
  An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE categorie CHANGE id id TINYINT(1) NOT NULL':                         
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of './chezbio/#sql-1983_d2' to './chezbio/categorie' (errno: 150)  

  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]                                                                                     
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of './chezbio/#sql-1983_d2' to './chezbio/categorie' (errno: 150)  

  [PDOException]                                                                                                          
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of './chezbio/#sql-1983_d2' to './chezbio/categorie' (errno: 150)
```

Why all these updates? The actual database is theoretically correctly designed.

The most important part of the problem:

(This could be related with the part where Doctrine wasn't able to sync with the online database.)

I'm trying to `select` a couple rows from my table.

For example, here I try to get all the rows from the `categorie` table:

```
$em->getRepository('AlembicBioBundle:Categorie')->findAll();
```

I have 4 rows in this table:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM categorie;
+----+----------+
| id | nom      |
+----+----------+
|  1 | FROMAGES |
|  2 | PAINS    |
|  3 | LEGUMES  |
|  4 | VIANDES  |
+----+----------+
```

When I use the Doctrine function (and not the manual query) I get 4 occurrences of the row "FROMAGES". *What could be causing this problem?*

The worst part is when I do:

```
$em->getRepository('AlembicBioBundle:Categorie')->findOneByNom('PAINS');
```

It returns these results:

```
Alembic\BioBundle\Entity\Categorie Object
(
    [nom:Alembic\BioBundle\Entity\Categorie:private] => PAINS
    [id:Alembic\BioBundle\Entity\Categorie:private] => 1
)
```

`PAINS` shouldn't have an id of 1...

I also get strange outputs if I try: `$repo->findXXX()`.

**Priorities:** I would like to find a way for my *find()-based-methods* to start working correctly. The database schema update is a secondary problem... (if this is not directly related to the findXXX() problem).

Comment: As I see in your dump sql statement, you set ``categorie`` id type to tinyint(1) and all your problems are caused by it (values for tinyint(1) only are 0, 1). To solve all problems, change id type definition to int.

Comment: @kibao, FYI `tinyint` can store -128 to +127 or 0 to 255 (unsigned)

Comment: findAll() returns an array.  It's pretty clear that you not iterating over the array properly.

Comment: @Cerad: I'm not iterating over the array, I'm using print_r on the whole result.
And the second example clearly shows that there is a problem. I'm using Doctrine for at least one year and that's the first time I see that.

Comment: @b.b3rn4rd I agree about ``tinyint``, but ``tinyint(1)`` displays only 0,1. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4401696/1851887 .

Comment: @kibao (1) -  is a display width it does not have external effect except if zerofill.is used

Comment: @Cerad, I think there's a problem with the DBAL layer: http://pastebin.com/X2mRf8DD

Comment: @MorganTouvereyQuilling please attach your doctrine configuration for Categoriee.

Comment: The import command is just a tool to get you started.  I suspect you have multiple things wrong.  Blow away your current entities then create and map category by hand and test your query using clean code.  Go on from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Prelude

Fixing your mapping metadata should be your *highest* priority. All sorts of strange things can happen when the mapping metadata is incorrect or not in sync with the database.

I suspect that most of the problems you describe come from the fact that doctrine uses an incorrect definition of identifier properties.

### Fix your mapping metadata

The command `doctrine:mapping:import` will try to create mapping metadata based on an existing database. This process is guesswork and will most probably not result in 100% correct mapping metadata.

It's important to go over the mapping metadata *manually* and correct what needs to be corrected. Please do so.

I suspect the identifier properties (the `id` columns in the db) are mapped using the "Doctrine mapping type" `boolean`. That's one of the reasons the `doctrine:schema:update` command will try to change the column type to `TINYINT(1)`. You probably want to use type `integer` here.

You can use the command `doctrine:schema:validate` to check if the mapping metadata is correct and in sync with the database.

It might also be possible you'll have a situation that's not solved easily. Not all constructs of all database vendors are supported by Doctrine out of the box. In many cases it can be solved, but please ask a new question dedicated to that particular case.

### Little advise

Please don't use commands/generators that alter your mapping metadata, nor entities for that matter.

Generating mapping metadata when there is non (at the start of a project) is fine, but my experience has shown that doing it repeatedly to alter the mapping metadata (and especially entities) creates more problems than it solves.

IMHO you should work from your code towards your database (not the other way around).

Comment: Thanks a lot! You were true about the import, for example, I have a bidirectional relation between two entities, but with a parameter, in the original tables. But Doctrine lost this field during the import. So I had to manually create an intermediate entity and change the relations between the three entities.
I dropped my tables and I created the tables from Doctrine.
You were also 100% true on the "boolean ID" and that caused a lot of problems.
That's working perfectly now.
Thanks for your answer. Take my like!