# What is the best way to represent a three-choice option in a database?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have got a list of objects that can be in three states only.

Simplified example of the data:

```
Substance State
H2O  solid
H2O  fluid
CO2  gas
...  ...
```

Is it better to use `TINYINT(2)` or `ENUM` or anything else? Should I insert the values right as they are (VARCHAR) or use numbers? External table of values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would reffer via an ID to an external table. THat table then shows the information as text.
In your select statements, you simply have to join. If you don't know what I'm talking about, ask me for an example :)

Though, I wouldn't use ENUM, for various reasons. Find the most important ones here: http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/

Comment: please set as best answer or upvote if you want? Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Nothing will be stored in less than one byte.

TINYINT(2) and an ENUM with 3 members will both result in 1 byte of storage.  Either will be fine.

The nice thing about ENUMs is that you can use plain English names, and they are stored compactly.  The bad thing about ENUMs is that they are not ANSI SQL.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am very new to the stuff.
> The nice thing about ENUMs is that ... they are stored compactly. 
A lot more compactly? I've got about 10 fields like this in my database, is it a lot better to store choices in ENUMs rather than in external tables?

Comment: If you have 1 to 255 choices, it MySQL will use 1 byte.  If you have 256 to 32,767 choices, MySQL will use 2 bytes.

Comment: I meant another kind of field. E.g. state(solid,fluid,gas), color(red,green,blue), size(small,medium,large) etc.

Answer (score 0):

Create a master table as state(id int , desc varchar),
According to the problem 
it will have

```
id   |  desc
1    |  Solid
2    |  Liquid
3    |  Gas
```

and in the solution(main) table refer the state table's id

Comment: I've got about 10 fields like this in my database, is it okay for performance?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can store the information in a column with type BIT and allow null values in the

column. The following is the mapping of value and your data.

H2O solid  --> TRUE

H2O fluid  --> FALSE

CO2 gas  --> NULL

Comment: Any reason why this got a down??

Comment: Possibly because there is zero difference between BIT and TINYINT, while being overly hackish. ENUM is still the better overall answer for a few values.

Comment: Yes, but whats wrong in using BIT??

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/488811/tinyint-vs-bit

Comment: Because using NULL to represent an actual value will land you in TDWTF for well-deserved mockery someday. For actual binary columns, no problem, unless they're extended.

Comment: And because with near certainty the requirement will pop up next week to store "CO" and you are stuck.  All the reports that assume the nullable BIT have to be redone, etc...