# How much space does nullable bit field take in SQL record and in SQL index?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008-r2, size, bit

As discussed in [Tinyint vs Bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488811/tinyint-vs-bit) if I have 8 bit fields in a table they will take only one tinyint of record size.

I assume that is true only when they are declared as `not null`.

What about nullable bit fields ? Are they taking 2 bits or whole tinyint ?

What about indexes ? How much space do nullable or not nullable bit fields take inside indexes in case if I use that field inside `INCLUDED` list combined with other bit or not bit fields ? What if bit is used in index expression together with other bit and non-bit fields ?

Comment: Well, you could try it - create tables using *your* schema, one with null and one with not null, populate them with *your* data, and see the difference in things like `sp_spaceused` at scale.

Comment: I agree with @AaronBertrand not only will you find out your answer by doing this but it will get you in the mindset of experimenting and testing out your hypothesis.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot speak for the specifics of SQL Server, (and I have gotten slammed for speaking without knowing the details).  However, a database only needs one bit per nullable field.  If a database dedicates more space it is because of some hoped for performance benefit, like 32-bit aligned integers.

Indexes in a typical RDBMS are b-trees.  A tree for a bit field is simply one branch for set bit and one branch for a clear bit.  If nullable, then another branch.  A the end of the tree, will be a list of records matching that condition.