# What is the datatype to store boolean value in MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, types, sqldatatypes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which MySQL Datatype to use for storing boolean values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289727/which-mysql-datatype-to-use-for-storing-boolean-values)

I am a .NET programmer and using MySQL database for the first time in my life.

I wanted to store boolean value, MySQL has `BIT`, but the .NET conversion of this datatype is `UINT64`.

There is another datatype `TINYINT(1)`, whose .NET equivalent is `System.Boolean` which will serve my purpose.

But why will I use `TINYINT(1)` (which can store value like 123, 22) instead of `BIT`, and **it will take more space than `BIT` also (I guess)**? It may be legal to use it but I dont think it is etical.

Can someone please help and clarify my doubt?

Comment: What do you mean by 'the .NET conversion'? How are you converting your db values into .net types? If you are converting manually, can't you use: Convert.ToBoolean(reader["columnName"]) This should convert the BIT value into a boolean no problem.

Comment: If you are taking DataReader and doing the above convertion then it works fine.
but if you are suing DataTable and trying to do the convertion then it is not working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MySQL have BOOL and BOOLEAN, but they are synonyms for TINYINT(1). A value of zero is considered false. Nonzero values are considered true. I guess someone at MySQL thought about it and decided TINYINT(1) is the preferred way to go. I've always used that myself.

There's some more info in this similar question: [What is the difference between BIT and TINYINT in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290223/what-is-the-difference-between-bit-and-tinyint-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3):

`BIT` doesn't work the way you think it does, It is generally used for storing [bitfields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitfield) and `BIT(M)` takes about `(M+7)/8` (integer arithmetic) bytes of storage. Using `BIT(1)` takes a whole byte anyway, the same as `TINYINT` so don't worry about it.

In case you are interested, the storage requirements for various types are located [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-requirements.html).

Answer (score 1):

> According to the MySQL manual you can use bool and boolean which are at the moment aliases of tinyint(1):

Reference: [Which MySQL data type to use for storing boolean values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289727/which-mysql-datatype-to-use-for-storing-boolean-values-from-to-php)

**Similar to MS SQL's Bit Datatype**:

```
0 = False    1 = True
```