# Integer field with character in where clause returns strange output

Tags: mysql

I have a column in a table with data type of tiny int. Its having values like 1 and 0. I tried a select query as

```
SELECT * from table_name where filed_name = 'Y';
```

This results me all records which is having zero in it. I didn't understand how query execution happens. Please help me to understand this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852337/true-false-vs-0-1-in-mysql true and false are synonyms for 1 and 0 refer to that previous question

Comment: I need to understand from my question is that how an integer field comparing with a character returns true(1). If you try above query as 'Select field_name = 'Y' from table_name' will return 1 as result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `string` is converted to a `number`, it becomes the value `0`.
Thats why your are getting all records with value `0`

```
SELECT * from table_name where filed_name = 'Y';
```

here **'Y' automatically converted to 0**

Use instead

```
SELECT * from table_name where filed_name = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks vikrant singh, Now I understood. Thanks lot

Answer (score 0):

`TINYINT` does not store strings values like `'Y'` or `'N'`, it stores integers `0` or `1`. If you want all datarows with value 'Y' you have to filter by 1 (integer) example:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myTinyColumn = 1
```