# MySQL: return "0" & "1" rather than "false" & "true"

Tags: sql

I need to return `true` or `false` rather than `1` & `0`, using following query:

```
select if(u.id is null,false,true) status
from user u
limit 10
```

the above query returns `status` with value 0 or 1 rather than `true` and `false`,

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: See [9.1.5 Boolean Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/boolean-literals.html).

Comment: [True/False vs 0/1 in mySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852337/true-false-vs-0-1-in-mysql)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want, you can return the values as *strings*:

```sql
SELECT IF(u.id IS NULL, 'false', 'true') as status
FROM user u
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: But these are strings, not true/false

Comment: Is there a way to return them as `true` & `false` without convert them to strings?

Comment: returning String will need more handlers from the receiver side

Answer (score 5):

TRUE/FALSE is equivalent to 1/0. It's just a matter of how your front end displays it.

If you need to return the strings "true" and "false" (which I don't suggest - handle that in the display) then you'll have to account for that as well:

`IF(IF(u.id ISNULL,false,true) = 1, 'TRUE', 'FALSE')`

Comment: Is there a way to return them as `true` & `false` without convert them to strings?

Comment: As I said, 1/0 **is** true/false, so your original statement was already returning them as true/false. It's just a matter of what you want to do with that in your front end. I would try to leave it as true/false and **not** convert it to strings. Let your front end or other code handle what it does with the 1/0 (true/false).

Answer (score 3):

MySQL has no boolean datatype, so you need to stick with 0 and 1 on the MySQL side:

```
select if(u.id is null, 0, 1) status_int
from user u
limit 10
```

If you prefer a boolean over 0/1 in PHP, you can cast it like this:

```
$status = (bool) $status_int;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue in lua. For some reason if the table column type is "tinyint" and you call 1 or 0 it will return as true and false. If you change the column type to "int" it will call and return in lua as 1 and 0.

Old post but I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score -1):

**[`IF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)**

You are missing single quotes.

```
select if(u.id is null,'false','true') status
from user u
limit 10;
```