# What's the difference between MySQL bit vs binary?

Tags: mysql

We can store binary values using either [`binary`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-varbinary.html) or  [`bit`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-field-literals.html) (up to 64 bits).

What is the difference between using `binary(n)` vs using `bit(m)` (where `n` = 8 × `m`)?

Are they recognized as the **same thing** by MySQL?

([Assuming using MySQL >= 5.0.3.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/290262/632951))

Answer (score 2):

You can store bits using BIT or BINARY - as you want. The BIT data type may be more usable in logic operations.

There is a small difference in storage:

- BINARY(M) requies exact number of bytes - M
- the length of the BIT type may vary, find more information here - [Data Type Storage Requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-requirements.html).

Comment: But what is the difference when we are using a multiple of 8 bits? Like `binary(2)` vs `bit(16)`?