# What is the difference between bit(1) and tinyint(1) in mysql

Tags: mysql

What is the different between `bit(1)` and `tinyint(1)` are they the same? This happens while we migrated data from a older version of mysql (maybe 5.1) to the latest version (say 5.5). Are they functionally the same

Comment: What does documentation say about this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290223/what-is-the-difference-between-bit-and-tinyint-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- BIT(m)

A bit-field type. `M` indicates the number of bits per value, *from 1 to 64*. The default is 1 if M is omitted.

- TINYINT(m)

A very small integer. The **signed range is -128 to 127**. The **unsigned range is 0 to 255**.

See [**Numeric Type Overview**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html)