# Invalid token in SQL query with UNION statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to execute a MySQL query by putting the email adresses in 3 different tables (oc_customer, oc_journal2_newsletter and oc_d_newsletter_subscriber) together. When all emails are put into 1 column, I want to group it to avoid duplicates and sort the data ascending.

I have the following query below, but each time I receive the message about the invalid token ')' before the query is effectively executed. The message is pointing to the line having the code .... `subscribed` = '1')....

Can somebody help me out to avoid this warning?

```
SELECT `emailTOTAAL`.`emailTOT`
FROM (
SELECT 
  `oc_customer`.`email` AS `emailTOT`
FROM
  `oc_customer`
WHERE
  `oc_customer`.`language_id` = '2' AND 
  `oc_customer`.`newsletter` = '1'
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  `oc_journal2_newsletter`.`email` AS `emailTOT`
FROM
  `oc_journal2_newsletter`
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  `oc_d_newsletter_subscriber`.`email` AS `emailTOT`
FROM
  `oc_d_newsletter_subscriber`
WHERE
  `oc_d_newsletter_subscriber`.`language_id` = '2' AND 
  `oc_d_newsletter_subscriber`.`subscribed` = '1') 
AS `emailTOTAAL`
GROUP BY   
 `emailTOTAAL`.`emailTOT`
ORDER BY
 `emailTOTAAL`.`emailTOT` ASC
```

Thanks,
Vicef

Comment: what's the data type of subscribed?

Comment: Data-type of subscribed is int(1)

Comment: Since this is `MySQL` syntax I removed `SQL-Server tag`.  You can revert if you have the reason to have both RDBMs tagged.

Comment: As an aside, note that the 1 in int(1) is almost meaningless

Comment: What happens when you just execute the unions, not as a subselect? Why not just UNION, and not UNION ALL, to remove duplicates?

Comment: if subscribed is supposed to be a Yes or No then don't use INT or TINYINT rather use BIT(1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290223/what-is-the-difference-between-bit-and-tinyint-in-mysql

Comment: I don't think "Invalid token" is a MySQL error message. Is this a popup in your IDE?

Comment: Hi SQLCliff, if simply UNION is used without subselect, the query is executed without error message but the data are not sorted...

Comment: Hi Barmar, the error message is generated by the application Maestro anySQL which is a tool to simplify the creation of mysql queries (for dummies like me). I will try the command in phpmyadmin as well.

Comment: Hi Barmar, very strange... my code is running well on phpmyadmin, so I suppose it is a bug in Maestro AnySQL So problem solved. The most important is that it runs smoothly on the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change `UNION ALL` to `UNION`, it should remove duplicates for you. Then you can get rid of the outer `SELECT` and the `GROUP BY`. Your query would then look like this:

```
SELECT 
    `email` AS `emailTOT`
FROM
    `oc_customer`
WHERE
    `language_id` = '2' AND 
    `newsletter` = '1'

UNION

SELECT 
    `email` AS `emailTOT`
FROM
    `oc_journal2_newsletter`

UNION

SELECT 
    `email` AS `emailTOT`
FROM
    `oc_d_newsletter_subscriber`
WHERE
    `language_id` = '2' AND 
    `subscribed` = '1'
ORDER BY `emailTOT` ASC
```

Comment: Hi Digital_Aaron, thank you for this simplified version. It is running smoothly on both phpmyadmin and Maestro Anysql and is having no duplicates indeed. It solved my problem! Thanks