# Appropriate data field type for true/false value?

Tags: mysql, integer, storage, tinyint, datafield

What's the most appropriate (read least data consuming) data field to store a true/false/1/0 value in a mySQL database?

I have previously used a one character long tinyint, but I am not sure if it's the best solution?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which MySQL Datatype to use for storing boolean values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289727/which-mysql-datatype-to-use-for-storing-boolean-values)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
tinyint(1)
```

Is basically aliased from the BOOL data type so it is fine.

[See here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?152,274043,274114#msg-274114)

In addition, this has already been covered here:

[Which MySQL data type to use for storing boolean values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289727/which-mysql-datatype-to-use-for-storing-boolean-values-from-to-php)