# why Boolean Data type are not working in MySQL?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, vb.net

I am using MySQL 5.5 and i linked it with my ASP.net Application .

i added a dataset to link my application within the MySQL stored procedure !!!

the problem is when i call any stored procedure which contains BOOLEAN like this one :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SpCatDetailsDML`(
    ParDetDescription TEXT,
    ParDetDescriptionAR TEXT,
    ParPrice INT,
    ParCreatedOn DATETIME,
    ParDisplayOrder INT,
    ParAllowDisplay BOOLEAN,
    ParPictureID BIGINT,
    ParShowTypeID BIGINT
)
BEGIN-- INSERT --
    INSERT INTO cms.tbcatdetails(CatID,CustomerID,DetTitle,DetTitleAR,ShoertDesc,ShoertDescAr,DetDescription,
                                 DetDescriptionAR,Price,CreatedOn,DisplayOrder,AllowDisplay,PictureID,ShowTypeID) 
    VALUES (ParCatID,ParCustomerID,ParDetTitle,ParDetTitleAR,ParShoertDesc,ParShoertDescAr,ParDetDescription,
            ParDetDescriptionAR,ParPrice,ParCreatedOn,ParDisplayOrder,ParAllowDisplay,ParPictureID,ParShowTypeID);
END
```

when i add this stored procedure to my dataset it will show me a warning becaues th ParAllowDisplay data type which is Boolean!!

so any suggestions???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>There is no Boolean data type in MySQL.</strike> Use `TINYINT(1)` instead.

See here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-overview.html

---

weird, I see `BOOL, BOOLEAN` in the URL mentioned above. Never used them.

*also, refer this post* [Which MySQL data type to use for storing boolean values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289727/which-mysql-datatype-to-use-for-storing-boolean-values-from-to-php)

Comment: @ajreal So, can I use `BOOL` as a data type while creating table? I fail to remember that I have ever used `BOOL`, I always use `TINYINT(1)`.

Comment: no you cant i already used BOOL and same problem with it !!

anyway i think TINYINT(1) will solve this one.


thank you

Comment: @ajreal, @HAJJAJ -- ah, great. Thanks. I was confused for a second.