# Recording yes or no in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which MySQL Datatype to use for storing boolean values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289727/which-mysql-datatype-to-use-for-storing-boolean-values)

I need to record a yes or no, 1 or 0, it doesn't really matter.
One for each day for a user. It is updated every day.

What structure should this table be?

Answer (score 2):

Have a table that called whatever you need it to be, for example users_daily with the columns

`id`

`user_id`

`yes (0 = no, 1 = yes) (tinyint),`

`timestamp`

Answer (score 2):

create a column of type [BIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html) for the table