# Alternative to lots of booleans in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I have a checkbox search form like this:

*Check all that interests you:*

- bowling
- billiard
- sweets

Can I request this data from a database instead of having to resort to adding tons of booleans to a database such as this?

(VenueId, IfBowling, IfBilliard, IfSweets)

And maybe just have one column that would contain all of those options that the venue itself has?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Alternative .. sure .. easy :

`User` table, `Interests` table, `UserInterests` table.

`UserInterests` is used to store many-to-many relation between `Users` and `Interests`, and contains values which are `FOREGN KEY`s from said tables.

P.S. You really should read [SQL Antipatterns](http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns) book. You would learn a lot from it.