# Boolean save as tinyint(1) in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I made table with some Boolean fields.

```
CREATE TABLE PM_ADMIN_LIST(
id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
username VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
mail VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
added_time INT,
super_admin VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
last_time INT,
last_ip VARCHAR(250),
see_user_per BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
change_user_per BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
see_people_per BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
change_people_per BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
add_people_per BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
remove_people_per BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
see_album_per BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
add_album_per BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
change_album_per BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
remove_album_per BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
see_music_per BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
add_music_per BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
change_music_per BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
remove_music_per BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
admin_per BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
yahoo_per BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
status_per BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
pm_per BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
ip_blocking_per BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE
);
```

But when I check it in phpmyadmin, `BOOLEAN` fields are `tinyint(1)` and they are `0` by default. I can make `1` to be `TRUE`. But when I use `===` in my PHP code, they can't be converted. (I should use `==` in `if`, `for`, `while` and I think it can make some bug in my system.)

So, how should I solve it? How should I get it BOOLEAN by default from mysql?

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289727/which-mysql-datatype-to-use-for-storing-boolean-values `BOOLEAN` is just an alias for `TINYINT(1)` - zero values are false, non-zero values are true. Why do you need it to compare it with `===`? PHP should handle conversions of `true/false` to 1/0.

Comment: You can't get boolean directly.

Comment: @SebastianWramba: I think it will be faster instead of saying php to convert 1 to TRUE .

Comment: This sounds like premature optimization which means: Don't care about the conversion (since it's necessary, see ThiefMaster's answer) and just use `==`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You usually don't get anything but strings in PHP when fetching data from the database. The types are solely used on the database side.

The field is a `TINYINT` because MySQL doesn't contain a `BOOLEAN` field at all.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'boolean' type in MySQL. You could just use the `==` check in PHP.