# MySQL Workbench: trying to create a boolean field for a table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to create a new column as boolean type, but I can't find it in the list..any help?

5.2.37 and ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 21):

There is no such thing as a 'boolean' in MySql unfortunately.

I think you need `tinyint(1)`.

This question has more: [Which MySQL data type to use for storing boolean values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289727/which-mysql-datatype-to-use-for-storing-boolean-values)

Answer (score 7):

Skip the workbench and use the command line

```
alter table my_table add column my_column BOOLEAN;
```

Comment: I just did this and the DataType was changed to TINYINT(1).

Answer (score 0):

To Create a **Boolean Column** in Table with default false

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD field_name tinyint(1);
```

if default true

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD field_name tinyint(0);
```

Comment: Rakesh your answer is not correct (or is partially correct), the value in parentheses isn't the default value, and do not affect the data type at all. It's called "Data-wise", or display size and it is merely a display width hint.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/55062