# How can I save a YES or NO value on a form to a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which MySQL Datatype to use for storing boolean values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289727/which-mysql-datatype-to-use-for-storing-boolean-values)

I have viewed many questions on this topic but I can not find an answer, 
 I have a HTML form with 10 questions, each with a radio button for yes or no to be selected.  when creating the table in the database (im using phpymadmin) what is the type I need to select for each question to store this yes no field?  I am a novice use at this but all answers appreciated!

Comment: What is it about the answers that you've found that don't suit your needs? What options are your currently considering?

Comment: the field could be anything, binary for 1 or 0 (yes or no) or even some kind of text field, varchar(3) or tiny text etc where you store the actual word, 'yes' or 'no'.

Comment: @martincarlin87 thank you, so if say i go for varchar option should i enter 'yes' and 'no' in values box? I will not be populating the table with data it will be coming from the form when it is submitted so i hope for the yes or no value to be read into the table depending on what the user has selected in the form.  thank u

Comment: @Claddagh it's entirely up to you, there's no right or wrong answer, all you have to do is decide which approach you like best and use it consistently. Personally I think 1 and 0 might be best as it's immediately understandable and language independent

Answer (score 3):

This depends entirelly on the use case.

Some possibilities are:

- Create a `TINYINT(1)` column and store `1` for yes and `0` for no;
- Create a `CHAR(1)` column and store `Y` for yes and `N` for no;
- Create a `VARCHAR(3) CHARSET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin` column and store 'yes' or 'no';

You are free to choose what fits your needs. And even these are only a few options.
What is really important is picking one and sticking to it as a standard for this kind of data.

Also, you may not need to represent the `no` values at all in case your data doesn't have an option to be null. You can only set the `yes` values and let the default be treated as `no`.

Comment: `VARCHAR(3) CHARSET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin` is better to store `yes` and `no`. Or you'll have surprises with spaces after `no` in a `CHAR` column.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I'll change the suggestion in the answer.