# Strange Hibernate exception with column type

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I am getting Hibernate exception:

> Wrong column type. Found: bit, expected: BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE

I have class User:

```
package mypackage;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "STATUS", columnDefinition = "BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE", 
                               nullable = false)
   private Boolean status = Boolean.TRUE;

   // getters and setters
}
```

This works properly if  Hibernate creates table itself in database. When

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

or

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
```

**But if**

1. I run my program and allow Hibernate to create this table
2. then I change the value of `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to the **validate**
3. and I run my program again with the table that has generated by Hibernate and with

   ```
   <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
   ```

so I get the exception:

> **org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in dbtest.user for column STATUS. Found: bit, expected: BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE**

Any idea what could be the reason for this behavior of Hibernate and how can I fix it?

I use `MySQL server 5.1` and `Hibernate 4.0.1`.

My `Run` class is just two lines:

```
 public class Run {

   public static void main(String[] main) {

     SessionFactory sessionFactory = 
                new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

     Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
   }
 }
```

The structure of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE USER (
    ID BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    STATUS TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    UNIQUE INDEX ID (ID)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT
AUTO_INCREMENT=2
```

My `hibernate.cfg`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/dbtest</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">root</property>

    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="connection.pool_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet">true</property>

    <mapping class="mypackage.User"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Hibernate creates the table with type `TINYINT` and I do not intermeddle on to the database and do not make any changes in the table manually! I'm just change the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to the `validate` and nothing else.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289727

Comment: I have not **default value** in my table if I choose `BIT DEFAULT 1` instead `BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE` in annotations. I get `STATUS BIT(1) NOT NULL` in db.

Comment: So my question can be rephrased as following way: **How to correctly declare a default value for a boolean field using the Hibernate annotation?**

Answer (score 2):

As the other guys already said: There is no boolean-column type in MySql. I had a similar problem and "created" an own dialect. It extends the default MySQL5Dialect and registers the stanard sql-type BOOLEAN to the MySql column type bit.

```
public class Mysql5BitBooleanDialect extends MySQL5Dialect{     
    public Mysql5BitBooleanDialect() {
        super();
        registerColumnType( java.sql.Types.BOOLEAN, "bit" );        
    }       
}
```

You can then use it by setting the dialect in your hibernate properties: hibernate.dialect=your.package.Mysql5BitBooleanDialect

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

```
private Boolean status = Boolean.TRUE;
```

Should result in a default value of true already.

Another way of solving this problem is using:

```
@PrePersist
public void prePersist()
{
    if ( status == null )
    {
         status = Boolean.TRUE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Wild guess** since I haven't used annotations form mapping, but here goes:

That columnDefinition looks like explicitly telling hibernate to use boolean column type with default value true, but MySql doesn't have boolean type, so maybe

```
columnDefinition = "BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE"
```

should be something like this

```
columnDefinition = "tinyint DEFAULT 1"
```