# Keeping queries separate, combining them, or using JOIN?

Tags: mysql

I have four basic tables setup for Role Based Access Control:

```
CREATE TABLE roles (
  role_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  role_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  valid ENUM('Y','N') DEFAULT 'Y',

  PRIMARY KEY (role_id)
);
CREATE TABLE permissions (
  perm_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  perm_desc VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  valid ENUM('Y','N') DEFAULT 'Y',

  PRIMARY KEY (perm_id)
);
CREATE TABLE role_perm (
  role_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  perm_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  valid ENUM('Y','N') DEFAULT 'Y',

  FOREIGN KEY (role_id)
    REFERENCES roles(role_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (perm_id)
    REFERENCES permissions(perm_id)
);
CREATE TABLE user_role (
  user_id VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  role_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  valid ENUM('Y','N') DEFAULT 'Y',

  FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES users(user_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (role_id)
    REFERENCES roles(role_id)
);
```

Now say I want to remove a specific role and all associations with it. I can do each query separately:

```
$sql = "UPDATE roles
        SET valid = 'N'
        WHERE role_id = :role_id";

$sql2 = "UPDATE user_role
         SET valid = 'N'
         WHERE role_id = :role_id";

$sql3 = "UPDATE role_perm
         SET valid = 'N'
         WHERE role_id = :role_id";
```

This code will execute the first query *only* if `role_id` is found, and likewise for the additional queries.

What I'm wondering is if I can combine all three queries into one statement with the exact same results, something like (I don't think this will work):

```
$sql = "UPDATE roles, user_role, role_perm
        SET roles.valid = 'N', user_role.valid = 'N', role_perm.valid = 'N'
        WHERE roles.role_id = :role_id AND user_role.role_id = :role_id AND role_perm.role_id = :role_id";
```

Or, would I be better off keeping the queries separate / using some type of JOIN?

Comment: AFAIK, no database supports updating multiple tables in one statement

Comment: @Bohemian Guess you don't know too much! ;-) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6bd25/2

Comment: @Strawberry That's why I didn't post it as an answer, and didn't make a definite statement - I'm always guarded about saying something "can't be done", because often, it can. Nice one! You should post it as an answer

Comment: I would but I'm not sure myself what happens to this in an InnoDB FK environment - have to go and play first...

Answer (score 1):

While something like the following is valid in MySQL, I suspect you really want to extend your FOREIGN KEY references and read up on ON UPDATE CASCADE...

```
UPDATE roles r 
  JOIN user_role ur
    ON ur.role_id = r.role_id
  JOIN role_perm rp
    ON rp.role_id = r.role_id
   SET r.valid = 'N'
     , ur.valid = 'N'
     , rp.valid = 'N';
```

Comment: I've attempted to use your query with a conditional id and it always returns 0 rows affected. Could you possibly update your answer with an example of how I might use the "ON UPDATE CASCADE" ?

Answer (score 0):

The last query, which you apparently didn't test, should work just fine.

As a side note: I think there are better options than enums to represent a boolean ('Y'/'N'). You can read through this topic to see which is good for you: [Which mysql datatype to use for storing boolean values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289727/which-mysql-datatype-to-use-for-storing-boolean-values)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the reason I don't think the last query will work is because it would require all three tables to have the role_id present in order to execute. What if only one table has the id?

Comment: All three tables have the role_id present. There has to be some reference to connect the records from the different tables. If you want to use another field to connect the records from the different tables, you just change the `WHERE`-clause.

Comment: the field is present in all three tables, but the conditional value may not be... Executing the queries separately only updates the table if the value matches; whereas the combined example requires all three tables to have that value.