# Is a mysql case value of datatype tinyint or varchar?

Tags: mysql

Naturally a boolean value is a boolean datatype (or bool, tinyint or whatever similar typo the current program language prefer to call it). But what kind of datatype is the column "boolean" in this following mysql-snippet?

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN reputation >= '9'
        THEN 'true'
        ELSE 'false'
      END AS boolean
    FROM profiles WHERE custid = '1'
```

Is it tinyint or varchar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term `boolean` here is actually a column alias, not a new data type you haven't seen before ;-)

```
> SELECT 'true' AS boolean
```

Output:

```
+---------+
| boolean |
+---------+
| true    |
+---------+
```

The type is whatever the expression yields, in this case a `CHAR` or `VARCHAR`.

Comment: Thanks, @Jack. I knew it was a column alias (I could had called it 'test' or basically anything) but your answer is absolutely spot on. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a `CHAR` type.

The `AS boolean` does not cast, it names the column.

Answer (score 0):

you can use tinyint(1) or if version is newer than 5 then BIT to store boolean values

read this
[Which MySQL Datatype to use for storing boolean values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289727/which-mysql-datatype-to-use-for-storing-boolean-values)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL manual says that bool and boolean are at the moment aliases of tinyint(1):

> Bool, Boolean: These types are synonyms for TINYINT(1). A value of
>   zero is considered false. Non-zero values are considered true.

You can check firing a select

```
select true, false
```