# Boolean not available for Toad MySql

Tags: mysql, database, toad

[image]

While designing the schema of my application, I noticed that there is no `Boolean` data-type option in the drop-down of **Toad** for **MySQL**.

Is there any other way to take `Boolean` data-type or **Toad** doesn't have a `Boolean` data-type ?

Note: I am using **Toad** for **MySQL** version 6.3.0.642.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which MySQL Datatype to use for storing boolean values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289727/which-mysql-datatype-to-use-for-storing-boolean-values)

Comment: I guess that's because MySQL doesn't have a *real* boolean type.

Comment: In MySQL I usually use `BIT` field type as boolean.

Answer (score 0):

`Boolean` is not in the pre compiled list in `toad`.

But it allows you to manually input data type `boolean` for the columns.
When used such data type, `toad` converts it into `tinyint(1)` and builds the table.

Alternatively you can use `BIT` data type to store `'1'` or `'0'` values. You can retrieve `bit` type column and directly compare as if it is a `boolean`.