# Symfony2 Change checkbox values from 0/1 to 'no'/'yes'

Tags: php, symfony, checkbox, enums

I created a form with one checkbox.

UserSettingsType.php:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    $builder->add('newsletter', 'checkbox', array(
        'label' => 'Newsletter erhalten',
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
        ),
        'required' => false,
    ));

}
```

In the UserSettings.php Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="newsletter", type="boolean")
 */
protected $newsletter;
```

In the User.php:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
protected $user_settings_id;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UserSettings", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_settings_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $settings;
```

In the PageController.php i handle the settings action:

```
public function settingsAction() {

    $user = $this->getUser();

    if ($user->getSettings() !== null) {
        $settings = $user->getSettings();
    } else {
        $settings = new UserSettings($user);
    }

    $settings_form = $this->createForm(new UserSettingsType(), $settings);

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $settings_form->bind($request);

        if ($settings_form->isValid()) {

            $user->setSettings($settings);
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();

        }

    }

    return $this->render('MyCompMyAppBundle:Page:settings.html.twig', array(
        'settings_form' => $settings_form->createView(),
    ));

}
```

I want to change the checkbox values from false (unchecked) / true (checked) to 'no' / 'yes' and change the definition of the newsletter field to: * @ORM\Column(name="newsletter", type="string", columnDefinition="ENUM('yes', 'no')")
It would be nice if there would be 'yes' and 'no' enum values in the database.
Please correct me if i am wrong: There is no way to change this via form element attributes, right?
I heard something about a [DataTransformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html):. But is there any easier way to realize this?

Comment: Why are you wanting to use no/yes rather then true/false?

Comment: This is a habit. It is better to read in the database and in MySQL statements. But maybe I should change my habit easily?

Comment: I would recommend that change of habit rather than trying to change everything else to fit. Also yes/no only fits in English so it's not very portable from a language side of things. Other good things come from being able to do boolean checks like `if ($user->getNewsletter())` rather the the longer (and possibly easily messed up with iffy spellings) `if ($user->getNewsletter() === 'yes'))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use ENUM for this!

In MySQL, use either data type `BIT(1)` or `TINYINT(1)` (=same as `BOOLEAN`). See here: [Which MySQL data type to use for storing boolean values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289727/which-mysql-datatype-to-use-for-storing-boolean-values)

In PostgreSQL, there is a true `BOOLEAN` type. But no `ENUM`. So if you're ever thinking about migrating, better get rid of `ENUM` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

do you want checkbox or radio button? for checkbox in peresentation use:

```
    $builder->add('newsletter', 'choice', array(
        'label' => 'Newsletter erhalten',
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
        ),
        'choices' => array(array('yes' => 'yes'), array('no' => 'no')),
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => true,
        'required' => false,
    ));
```