# Wrong column type (oracle) Found: number, expected: boolean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, junit

1. I am using jdk 1.6.45 spring 3.1 hibenate 4 jpa-2 junit 4 and maven
2. when i run the junit
3. I am getting the below error

   [Issue Description](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1011905)

If I remove the below line in persistance xml .., validation skipped and working fine

```
          <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
```

what needs to be done to the execute junit validation

Comment: Have you seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/289727/3364187)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect to org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

Not It is working perfect.