# mysql load data, issue with boolean field

Tags: mysql, boolean, load-data-infile

I m loading data in a mysql table with the instruction :

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "/home/user123/Documents/PartageVB/export tables/pays.csv" INTO TABLE T_PAYS FIELDS TERMINATED BY ";" LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"(id, name, cit,actif);
```

In the file pays.csv, the column cit is boolean, and gets the value 1 or 0.

My problem is that once LOAD DATA is done, cit always gets the value 1 in the mysql table.

Does anyone know where I m wrong?

In the table, cit type is Bit(1).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use "TINYINT(1)" instead of "Bit(1)".It might work.
[Refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289727/which-mysql-datatype-to-use-for-storing-boolean-values)