# WHY MYSQL Error 1406 Data too long for column?

Tags: mysql

From my application registration form, I 'm trying to insert check box value into mysql table but it throw an error **1406 Data too long for column** . The value of tick box is 0 or 1. and my table structure is, create table test( checkbox_response bit(1))...

I had gone through something and I found the solution for this problem. The solution is, I just changed my sql-mode **SET @ @global.sql_mode = ''**... After the proper insertion was happened.

Though My Datatype size is fit for check box value, Why it throws an 1406 error?

Answer (score 0):

Please use "TINYINT(1)" instead of "Bit(1)".

Comment: Thanks for your reply Adarsh... Actually The signed range of TINYINT is 0 to 255 and for BIT is 0 to 64. I really wanted to know Why this has been happened, Though Check box value come under the datatype range. would you please explain that?

Comment: [refer this]


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289727/which-mysql-datatype-to-use-for-storing-boolean-values