# SQL BIT column must be blank vs TRUE on output, NULL vs 1 on input

Tags: mysql, sql, database, null, string

This is what my table needs to look like:

```
MovieID  Title            YearReleased  RatingID  BW     Subtitles
1        Quiet Man, The   1952          1       
2        McLintock!       1963          3       
3        Thin Man, The    1934          0         TRUE  
4        Tampopo          1985          4                TRUE
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
CREATE TABLE MOVIE
(MOVIE_ID VARCHAR (2) PRIMARY KEY,
TITLE VARCHAR(20),
YEAR_RELEASED DATE,
RATING_ID VARCHAR(1),
BW BIT,
SUBTITLES BIT);

INSERT INTO MOVIE
VALUES 
(1,'Quiet Man, The',1952,'1',NULL,NULL),        
(2,'McLintock!',1963,'3',NULL,NULL),    
(3,'Thin Man,The',1934,'0',(1),NULL),
(4,'Tampopo',1985,'4',NULL,(1));
```

I don't understand how to insert the data for a blank spot and the true values. :\ What I get is something that looks like this:

```
MovieID     Title             YearReleased RatingID BW      Subtitles
    1       Quiet Man, The    1952         1        NULL    NULL
    2       McLintock!        1963         3        NULL    NULL
    3       Thin Man, The     1934         0        1       Null
    4       Tampopo           1985         4        NULL    1
```

My professor told me to go online and find the answer because it's there. -_-

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: are you working on MySql  or Oracle Sql? for MySql follow [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289727/which-mysql-datatype-to-use-for-storing-boolean-values)

Comment: in the last table where there are nulls need to be blank and the 1 need to say tru i don't get how to write the code to make it look like that

Comment: same title as "My pet is called Bingo"

Comment: A table is one thing and a query result is another. What was your assignment? Do you have a choice about the table definition, the table contents, the update expression and/or a final query? What were you given and what were you supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong, in your query to display the values  use the `CASE` statement to replace the `NULL` values with empty string, 0 with False, and 1 with true. Something like

```
SELECT MOVIE_ID,
  Title,
  YEAR_RELEASED,
  RATING_ID,
  CASE 
    WHEN BW IS NULL THEN ' ' 
    WHEN BW = 1     THEN 'TRUE'
    WHEN BW = 0     THEN 'FALSE' 
  END AS BW,
  CASE
    WHEN Subtitles IS NULL THEN ' '
    WHEN Subtitles = 1     THEN 'TRUE'
    WHEN Subtitles = 0     THEN 'FALSE' 
  END AS Subtitles
FROM Movie;
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56a10/1)

This will give you:

```
| MOVIE_ID |          TITLE | YEAR_RELEASED | RATING_ID |   BW | SUBTITLES |
|----------|----------------|---------------|-----------|------|-----------|
|        1 | Quiet Man, The |          1952 |         1 |      |           |
|        2 |     McLintock! |          1963 |         3 |      |           |
|        3 |   Thin Man,The |          1934 |         0 | TRUE |           |
|        4 |        Tampopo |          1985 |         4 |      |      TRUE |
```

You can't insert it as blank string as the column data type is `bit`.

Note that:

- `NULL` is different from the empty string.
- False values are entered as `0` in the `bit` column data type.
- You can't enter the values `1952`, `1963` etc in a `DATE` data type column, instead use the [`YEAR` data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/year.html) as in the sql fiddle demo.

Comment: No dbms specified, so I'd recommend COALESCE instead of ISNULL.

Comment: @jarlh - the user just decided it is Mysql, I updated my answer. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you looking for?

```
INSERT INTO MOVIE
VALUES 
(1,'Quiet Man, The',1952,'1','',''),        
(2,'McLintock!',1963,'3','',''),    
(3,'Thin Man,The',1934,'0',(1),''),
(4,'Tampopo',1985,'4','',(1));
```

you can also set an default empty string in your create table