# How to store boolean datatype in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, boolean-logic

**Which datatype is used for storing `true/false` information in MySQL?**

Especially when writing and reading with a PHP-Script.

Over time I have used and seen several approaches:

> ```
> tinyint, varchar fields containing the values 0/1,
> varchar fields containing the strings '0'/'1' or 'true'/'false'
> and finally enum Fields containing the two options 'true'/'false'.
> ```

Not one seems optimal, I prefer the `tinyint 0/1 variant`, since automatic type conversion in PHP gives me boolean values rather simply.

So, is there a type designed for boolean values which I have overlooked?

Do you see any advantages/disadvantages by using one type or another?

Comment: tinyint is  a good option.

Comment: Here is a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289727/which-mysql-datatype-to-use-for-storing-boolean-values

Answer (score 3):

There are lot's of options.

For compatibility with a lot of different MySQL clients, client libraries, ORM, etc. we've settled on

```
 col  TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED COMMENT 'boolean, ...'
```

And we don't use the `TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED` datatype for anything except boolean. (Where we can, we add `NOT NULL`.) We add a comment, with "boolean" as the first string, followed by the actual description.

Note that the **`(1)`** doesn't influence the range of values that can be stored. It can still hold integer values from 0 thru 255. We just include it to help distinguish our "boolean" type from other TINYINT values, which are not booleans.

We handle a NULL value as NULL, a value of `0` as "false", and any other value is considered "true"... the same way that MySQL interprets an integer value in a boolean context.

We've not encountered any clients that can't handle an integer type.

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL 5.0.3 and higher, you can use BIT or TINYINT.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289727/which-mysql-datatype-to-use-for-storing-boolean-values) you have a more elaborated answer

Comment: Note that some clients/client libraries/ORM mappings don't play nice with the `BIT` datatype. But we don't run into that problem with the integer type.

Answer (score 1):

FOR mysql use the type  **BOOLEAN NOT NULL** type 
like

```
ALTER TABLE `products` ADD `test` BOOLEAN NOT NULL;
```

if Boolean not working use tiny int like
**TINYINT(1) NOT NULL**
eg. `ALTER TABLE`products`ADD`test`TINYINT(1) NOT NULL;`

**important**
 TINYINT(1) value inside tinyint is necessary.

Comment: Why is the **`(1)`** following `TINYINT` necessary? It doesn't impact the range of values that can be stored.

Comment: YES need necessary for tiny-int because it range from -128 to 127 so need to specify if you use tiny int..

Comment: Yes, the range of values that can be stored in **`TINYINT`** is -128 to 127. That's *identical* to the range of values that can be stored in **`TINYINT(1)`**.  Again, there is no explanation as to *why* it would be necessary to use `TINYINT(1)` vs `TINYINT`. The range of values that can be stored is *identical*. What difference does it make?