# Where condition with false returning all values

Tags: mysql

its just simple where condition, but its working getting all data from the data table. Not considered the value **false**

```
select * from `api_auth` where `auth_key` = false;
```

Comment: Try using `auth_key IS FALSE`

Comment: @Viki888 Why??? `SELECT 1 = 0 = false; -> 1 `

Comment: Remove auth_key out of the single inverted commas

Comment: @PrashanthBenny Why???

Comment: Because it is considering your column as a string.....

Comment: @PrashanthBenny There's no inverted commas here.

Comment: @PrashanthBenny you are talking about backticks and they are used only to escape mysql reserved words if used as a table/column name. Here are useless but harmless

Comment: what is the data type of the `auth_key` column?

Comment: data type of the auth_key column **text**

Comment: Ops.... My bad....

Comment: If it's text, probably using = 'false' would fix... Right? Sql considers false as Boolean probably...

Comment: @PrashanthBenny you means problem with sql ?

Comment: not a problem with sql.... its a wrong interpretation..!

Comment: @LelioFaieta my bad! my misinterpretation :D

Comment: @KalidassP if you have a column which you are using to represent true and false, then the "text" data type is not really a good choice. Some better suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289727/which-mysql-datatype-to-use-for-storing-boolean-values

Comment: @KalidassP did the issue get fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Here, the issue seems to be with the **wrong usage of `false` in this statement as a Boolean datatype**.

Since the datatype of `auth_key` column is `text` as you have mentioned as an answer to @ADyson, and you have used the Boolean `false` to compare the string datatype in the column, MySql is not populating the results as you require.

comparing you text column with a matching datatype(i.e., string) would fix the error.

i.e.,

```
select * from `api_auth` where `auth_key` = 'false';
```

Comment: whilst the solution will work, I dispute this statement: "wrong interpretation of false as a keyword or Boolean datatype by MySql compiler." MySQL is interpreting it correctly as the boolean literal FALSE (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/boolean-literals.html). But that boolean value is not equal to the text string "false", hence why it doesn't restrict the results as the OP wants. The real issue of course, is that OP is abusing the "text" data type to store boolean values and should use another more suitable data type.

Comment: @ADyson you are right... I meant to say it that way... :O

Comment: @ADyson i have edited the answer! hope it means the same :) . i am a bit bad in articulation! please forgive....

Comment: @ADyson thank you so much! you have been very helpful!