# save boolean in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following select in my form, which I need to save in my database:

```
<select name="openhours" class="form-control selectpicker" >
    <option value=" " >Open Sundays</option>
    <option>Yes</option>
    <option>No</option>
</select>
```

I made a boolean column in MySQL database. But first of all I cannot figure out if a boolean column still is a name for `tinyint`?

I have made the following insert function which is working perfectly fine. But how can I bind a boolean in my insert function?

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["headline"], $_POST["description"])) {
    $head = trim($_POST["headline"]);
    $desc = trim($_POST["description"]);


    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO stores (headline, description) VALUES (?, ?)");
                    // bind variable
                    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $head, $desc);   // bind

                    // execute prepared statement 
                if ($stmt->execute()) {
                    $success = true;
                }

                // close statement
                $stmt->close();

                // close connection
                $mysqli->close();   

if($success) {
    echo "Insert Succesfull";
} else {
    echo "Failed: " .  $stmt->error;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Your options need a value attribute. IOW ```<option value='1'>Yes</option>```

Comment: Like: `<option value='0'>No</option>` and `<option value='1'>Yes</option>` ? How would I bind that in my prepared statement?

Comment: @McDuck4 For a boolean value, I recommend ENUM type of field to use in mysql, rather than tinyint

Comment: Why an ENUM? That type is used most for boolean?

Comment: there's no POST array for `openhours`, nor matching inputs for the other POST arrays.

Comment: @SloanThrasher values aren't always required for `<option>`, although recommended. `<option>1</option>` would have worked.

Comment: Don't think about it by the hard way. Boolean means only two values or indeed, one value and any other value. I have tried many ways to store boolean descriptive storage. such as CHAR(1) with default Y or N then in your script you may check for `if ($it == 'Y'){}else{}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add these lines to your code.

Give options a value

```
<option value="1">Yes</option>
<option value="0">No</option>
```

To get posted value

```
$oh = isset($_POST["openhours"])&&$_POST["openhours"]=="1"?1:0;
```

Update query

```
"INSERT INTO stores (headline, description,openhours) VALUES (?, ?,?)"
```

Bind it

```
$stmt->bind_param('ssi', $head, $desc, $oh);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is that all to set my booelan? I thought it was more complicated.

Comment: @McDuck4 yes, it should update your db accordingly. If any problems just comment me. If works accept as answer please.

Answer (score 1):

You can Use `TINYINT(1)`. 
`BOOLEAN` are synonyms of `TINYINT(1)` in MySQL . Zero is false, anything else is true

check the MySQL manual for this : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-overview.html

this answer should give you the right explanation of your issue :  [Which MySQL data type to use for storing boolean values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289727/which-mysql-datatype-to-use-for-storing-boolean-values)

lastly make sure to give values to your select options thanks !