# How to change mysql data types?

Tags: php, mysql, types, datatables

I have mysql table for car's accessories like "airconditioner, park assist, cd player, brake assist" and etc. All of them are in `INT(11)`. But I am using them like `1`, if the car has this one, or `NULL`, if it hasn't. Should I change this `INT(11)` with something other? If I can, please tell me how?

Comment: Use boolean, which is `tinyint(1)`. Then you can use 1/0 instead.

Comment: Please post your table structure.  There may or may not be something wrong with what you are doing.

Comment: That `11` doesn't mean number of stored digits. Anyway, you may want to take look at `char(1)`.

Comment: I hope these aren't individual columns :-(

Answer (score 1):

You'll save a little disk space on your database server by making this change. You don't need to change your application logic at all; both `TINYINT` and `INT` are integers you can compare to 1 or 0.

Note that MySQL *ignores* the `11` in `INT(11)` and the `1` in `TINYINT(1)`.  `INT` values are 32-bit numbers, and `TINYINT` values are 8-bit numbers.

Unless you have millions of rows in the table, making this change will probably save you only a tiny amount of space. It's already cost you more in your time to ask this question than it will save over a decade of running this database.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is creating flags to indicate yes or no values, so that is more suitable for a boolean data type, you can learn how to use boolean values in MySQL from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289727/which-mysql-data-type-to-use-for-storing-boolean-values).

Comment: I changed it to tinyint(1), because my code is <?php if($result->AirConditioner==1)
{?> Am I right?

Comment: ...and either way, it's probably a bad idea.