# Laravel Migration Returning Invalid SQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mariadb

I am running Laravel 6.0.2 and my migration up method is as follows:

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->boolean('admin')->default(false);
            $table->boolean('manager')->default(false);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
});
```

```sql
create table `users` (
  `id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
  `first_name` varchar(255) not null,
  `last_name` varchar(255) not null,
  `email` varchar(255) not null,
  `password` varchar(255) not null,
  `admin` tinyint(1) not null default ('0'),
  `manager` tinyint(1) not null default ('0'),
  `remember_token` varchar(100) null,
  `created_at` timestamp null,
  `updated_at` timestamp null
) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
```

I have run that SQL on an online syntax checker and that is giving me and error on the `admin tinyint(1) not null default ('0'),` line.

I am not sure whether this is a Laravel 6.0.2 bug as it seemed to be working before that update.

Has anyone run into this issue and know of the fix?

Comment: Try passing a 0 instead of False on the default

Comment: The SQL syntax looks valid for MariaDB 10.3. Which "online syntax checker" is reporting the error? Does that "online syntax checker" enforce the same rules as MariaDB? Does MariaDB report a syntax error? (Seems like what needs to be fixed is the "online syntax checker", not Laravel or MariaDB)

Comment: @aynber no luck

Comment: Please try to set `'strict' => 'false'` in the connection properties (config/database.php)

Comment: @spencer7593 my tavis ci is failing due to the issue. is it possible to use mariadb on travis ci?

Comment: @dparoli no luck with that either

Comment: Reference: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#mariadb   i'm not familiar with travis ci. The generated SQL syntax is valid for MariaDB 10.3.x. It may be also valid in MariaDB 10.2.x

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is pretty easy to fix and pretty easy to overlook. My guess is you've been looking at it for too long.

Your `DEFAULT`s don't need parenthesis or the quotes. The quotes are only there for strings, not `int`s, and the parens are only needed if it's a subquery (which isn't likely would actually work, but I haven't tried it).

http://www.w3webtutorial.com/mysql/mysql-default-constraint.php

Comment: Unfortunately, this advice would work if the OP was creating the schema manually, but the Laravel migrations are being used instead.

Comment: Keep in mind the SQL seen in the question is generated from the `Schema::create()` function; it's not as simple as "omitting the quotes" per-say.

Comment: The SQL syntax appears to be valid at least for MariaDB 10.3, so the SQL doesn't necessarily need to be fixed. (also, don't link to w3fools)

Answer (score 0):

In mysql boolean type is tinyint 0 false 1 true ...

```
$table->boolean('admin')->default(0);
```

Comment: Do you have any documentation on why it should be `0` instead of `false`? I understand that it's evidently translating `false` to a string of 0 incorrectly, but any documented information as to why? Adding that could make this go from a good answer to The Answer.

Comment: Read the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289727/which-mysql-data-type-to-use-for-storing-boolean-values/289767