# In laravel migration, it change the boolean type to tinyint(1)

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

Currently my migration:

```
$table->string('avatar');
$table->boolean('online')->default(0);
$table->boolean('adult')->default(0);
```

In the schema : 
[Generated schema for migration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXrLk.png)

Comment: most of the database systems do not have `boolean` type and thus Laravel use tinyInt with a single byte of data allowing only `0` or `1` where 0 means false and 1 means true. its not an error, but the expected result. this is how many of these database system works.

Comment: @Pusparaj this should be an answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which MySQL data type to use for storing boolean values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289727/which-mysql-data-type-to-use-for-storing-boolean-values)

Comment: @cbaconnier: Yeah, you are right. This make sense :). Thanks

Comment: @Pusparaj: Thanks for you answer

Comment: @cbaconnier: Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1):

```
Schema::table('tablename', function ($table) {
$table->tinyInteger('online')->change();
});
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.