# Cannot change to BOOLEAN a column in table using DBeaver

Tags: mysql, boolean, dbeaver, tinyint

I have one table in MySQL where I would like to change the "Data type" of two columns in DBeaver (version 22.3.4). The two columns are `MD_Estimated` and `BL_Estimated` as you can see in this image:

[image]

However, when I save the changes, this is the code which is run:

```
ALTER TABLE Kruda_Denta_Datumbazo.CrownDiameterTable MODIFY COLUMN MD_Estimated BOOL NULL;
ALTER TABLE Kruda_Denta_Datumbazo.CrownDiameterTable MODIFY COLUMN BL_Estimated BOOL NULL;
```

But the problem is that it does not return any error, but the "Data type" is not saved as `BOOL`, but as `tinyint(1)`, as you can see in this image:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which MySQL data type to use for storing boolean values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289727/which-mysql-data-type-to-use-for-storing-boolean-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TINYINT(1) and boolean are synonymous In MySQL. Bool is converted to TINYINT(1) under the hood.