# Using mysql BIT columns with perl DBI

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I converted some `TINYINT` columns that held 0/1 to `BIT`, as there would be storage savings. This is on MySQL 5.7, latest DBI, my DBD::mysql is 3 versions old (4.050 - the latest suddenly requires mysql 8). I expected my code to not have to change, as DBI usually does the right thing for bind variables etc. So, since this works the same for both BIT and TINYINT:

```
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO TABLE thetable (bitcol) VALUES (0)");
```

I was hoping the bind version to also work:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO TABLE thetable (bitcol) VALUES (?)");
$sth->execute(0);
```

Nope! I get `1` stored (overflow basically). I read the documentation, and I came up with this, which is a bit cumbersome when I have lots of bind values so prepare to use the shorthand with an array passed to execute, but in any case:

```
use DBI qw(:sql_types);
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO TABLE thetable (bitcol) VALUES (?)");
$sth->bind_param(1, 0, SQL_BIT);
$sth->execute();
```

Nope! Still the same. The only way the bind works is if I use `pack` to explicitly pass the bit.

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO TABLE thetable (bitcol) VALUES (?)");
$sth->execute(pack('b1', 0));
```

And then, reading is the same, the only way I can read the `SELECT` results is with `unpack`.

I understand that `BIT` is actually for storing bits, and bits are obviously different than the 8-bit characters `0` and `1`, but since the SQL for `INSERT` works fine with 0/1 and the `SELECT` outputs `0/1` and not bits in the command line, I'd expect there to be a simple way to use the `BIT` columns for storing 0/1 (true/false) essentially.

Am I missing something?

Edit: I do understand how BIT works with relation to potential savings. It would be a few GB if I did it on the tables that use many of these fields, so it might be significant, but it all depends *exactly* on my question. If you have to pack/unpack the savings start feeling smaller.

Comment: `BIT` may save you some space, but `BOOLEAN` is easier to work with if you need to query them with SQL IMHO --- This is because you can use the aliases of `TRUE` and `FALSE`.  Really you are splitting hairs with the space savings.

Comment: Using `BIT` is rarely worth the trouble. Read the answer from Thor here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8838412/20860

Comment: Secondary thought -- `BOOL` is really the same thing as  `TINYINT(1)` --- But allowing you to use aforementioned aliases.   As mentioned above .. Unless you have thousands of true/false (boolean) fields -- The space savings will be so minute, your time will be better spent optimizing your dataset in other ways.

Comment: @BillKarwin It is 38 0/1 fields on a table that currently has over 20 million lines and is increasing. So I would be saving near a GB just on this. We are using Cloud SQL, and each GB adds quite a bit to the DB restore time should something go wrong, in addition to the costs (it's not just a GB if you include snapshots, HA etc). But it's not worth a lot of trouble, so if I have to pack/unpack, it's not the same value/trouble...

Comment: So 38 `TINYINT` columns would be stored in 38 bytes per row. 38 `BIT(1)` columns may be compacted to 5 bytes per row. That's a savings of 33 bytes per row. Multiplied by 20 million rows, that's 660 million bytes at best, and probably not really that much, because InnoDB doesn't pack rows into pages perfectly anyway. If I brought this up in an engineering meeting at most companies, they would ask why we are even discussing it. Just allocate a slightly larger storage volume. Businesses usually prioritize development productivity higher than a tiny amount of storage overhead.

Comment: We are discussing it because, as I said, this is one example table. Multiply it by several tables. Our main concern is not the space per se, but the restore time for disaster recovery. I expect that it will not affect the point in time restore via the transaction log, but it will affect restoring the snapshot, as that's I/O limited and currently it is slower than we are comfortable with. Again, the question is exactly to see if the (not great, but not non-existent) benefits of BIT are worth it - if we have to pack/unpack probably not. But I'd still like to know if that's the case or not!